# Getting error while using httpd -v command in script

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, scripting

I wrote a script to check the details of Web server's(RHEL) and save the output into a file. But the script is not passing the command httpd -v in the loop.

Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat hosts`
do
echo "======$i======" >>/home/user/output.txt;
ssh $i \
'echo -n "Apache version: " ; httpd -v |grep -i Unix; \
echo -n "CPU Info: " ; cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep processor|wc -l; \
cat /proc/meminfo |egrep "MemTotal"; \
cat /proc/meminfo |egrep "MemFree"; \
cat /proc/meminfo |egrep "SwapTotal"; \
cat /proc/meminfo |egrep "SwapFree"; \
echo -n "VM Status: " ; ps -ef |grep -i vmtoolsd|egrep -v grep|wc -l; \
echo -n "Apache config: " ; ls -ltr /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf' >>/home/user/output.txt;
done
```

Please help me to fix the error..

Comment: `httpd` is in my experience seldom in a normal path, make sure that you specify the full path to the executable. And update the question with  the error message that you get (or specify that you didn't get any).

Comment: After adding the full path of httpd command, script is working fine without any error message. Thank a lot for your valuable information.

Comment: Since Anthon's answer worked for you, you should [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.
Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`httpd` is usually not a command that is in the default login path. You better explicitly specify the full path to the executable e.g. `/usr/sbin/httpd`.